# How to prevent the installation of extensions in Chromium browsers (Vivaldi)

Tags: browser, windows-registry, browser-addons, vivaldi

I want to prevent the installation of any extension on all my browsers. Chrome was easy enough I found out how to do it using regedit going to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > WOW6432Node > Policies and then using "ExtensionInstallBlocklist", Microsoft edge was also simple. The problem is a browser like vivaldi, Vivaldi isn't popular enough to have its own dedicated guide like the other two.

Also unlike the other two Vivaldi was installed per user so it's at User/Appdata/Local/Vivaldi instead of C/Program Files/Google/Chrome so it's not located at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but instead at HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Personally I am not comfortable enough to fiddle around in regedit and break stuff. I can uninstall Vivaldi and then install it system wide so it's at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but after that I don't know what to do and don't want to cause problems.

TL;DR how do you block extension installation for other browsers like Vivaldi, Firefox, Opera

Comment: It's the same as in Chrome and Edge; the key is under `$\Software\Policies\Vivaldi`, where $ is HKLM or HKCU. I found this at https://admx.help; consider bookmarking that site and looking there whenever you have extension or policy questions.

Comment: Yep that worked out well enough. That website you linked was very helpful. I found the exact reg keys at https://admx.help/?Category=VivaldiBrowser&Policy=Vivaldi.Policies.Chromium::ExtensionInstallBlacklist